# SVD decomposition of matrix

Tags: matrices

> Is it correct to say that a matrix $A$ and the matrix $A^HA$ have the same eigenvectors?

**Proof:**

$$
A= U \Sigma V^* \\
A^HA= U \Sigma^2 U^H
$$

Am I correct?

Comment: Is this about singular value decomposition or about $SVD$ decomposition?

Comment: Shouldn't $U\Sigma^2 U^H$ be $AA^H$ rather than $A^H A$? ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 1):

The matrix $A=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$ has two one-dimensional eigen spaces, one generated by the vector $[1,1]^T$ and one by $[1,-1]^T$.

On the other hand, $A^HA=I$, so every vector in $\mathbb C^2$ is an eigenvector of $I$.

Conclusion:

No. The set of eigenvectors of $A^HA$ is not the same as the set of eigenvectors of $A$.